# Finding the limit of $(x-2)^5\ln(x-2)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you find the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)^5\ln(x-2)$$

I did

$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{\ln(x-2)}{\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^5}}$

Then I took Mr. l'Hôpital's rule

$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x-2}}{\dfrac{-5}{(x-2)^4}}$

Then I did the following

$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{1}{x-2}\dfrac{(x-2)^4}{-5}$

I got

$\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{(x-2)^4}{-5}=\dfrac{0}{-5}=0$

But would this be correct?

Comment: I think you meant $\;(x-2)\;$ outside the logarithm, yet in the first two times you wrote $\;(x-5)\;$ . Fix this.

Comment: yes sorry i got confused.

Comment: arregla también el título de la pregunta.

Comment: After the corrections you did, Fernando, your answer is correct and so is the use of l'H, but after you wrote "I got" it must be $\;\frac{(x-2)^3}{-5}\;$

Comment: The derivative of $(x-2)^{-5}$ is $-5(x-2)^{-6}$. But the method is basically correct.

Comment: yes I made a mistake with my derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you should be evaluating $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{(x-2)^5}{-5},$$ your approach is perfect. Nicely done.

Do be careful with your notation, though. I imagine that it's shaky, here, only because you aren't familiar with LaTeX. You'll want something like $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 2^+}(x-2)^5\ln(x-2) &= \lim_{x\to 2^+}\cfrac{\ln(x-2)}{\frac1{(x-2)^5}} & \\ &= \lim_{x\to 2^+}\cfrac{\frac1{x-2}}{\frac{-5}{(x-2)^6}} & (\text{L'Hopital's rule})\\ &= \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac1{x-2}\cdot\frac{(x-2)^6}{-5} & \\ &= \lim_{x\to 2^+}\frac{(x-2)^5}{-5} & \\ &= \frac0{-5}\\ &= 0. &\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes I am sorry I got confused.

Comment: @Fernando: Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The method is basically correct, but you made a mistake in computing a derivative. Write
$$
(x-2)^{-5}
$$
and then use the rule $x^n \to nx^{n-1}$ which in this case gives $-5(x-2)^{-6}$. For the rest the computation is correct:
$$
\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)^5\ln(x-2)=
\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\ln(x-2)}{(x-2)^{-5}}\overset{H}{=}
\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)^{-1}}{-5(x-2)^{-6}}=
\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-2)^5}{-5}=0
$$

---

It would be easier by computing first
$$
\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)\ln(x-a)=
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\ln(x-a)}{(x-a)^{-1}}\overset{H}{=}
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)^{-1}}{-(x-a)^{-2}}=
\lim_{x\to a}-(x-a)=0
$$
and then writing
$$
\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)^5\ln(x-2)=
\lim_{x\to2}(x-2)^4\cdot(x-2)\ln(x-2)=0\cdot0=0
$$